# Multiple terminal windows in Windows Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu downloaded from the Windows Store in Windows 10. It doesn't seem to be possible to use multiple terminal windows. Is the only way then to install a GUI and use this with the X server. I feel like this would defeat the point of using Ubuntu for Windows. I can imagine it working quite slowly. And I have to download 2GB of GUI.

Comment: did you invoke the terminal from out of the GUI? Then try right (other) mouse button and say New Window. That's what you mean? It is a bullshit feature  only to open one terminal and then let the user alone with this issue. Similar with alt-tab where there is only one terminal accessible. you can configure this (different issue).

Comment: Opening Ubuntu in Command Prompt as suggested below solves my current issue. :)

Comment: @opinion_no9 I have observed that the apps we install from Store doesn't allow to open multiple instances/windows. Same is with Ubuntu app. It doesn't allow to open another window. On right click there are 3 options: App Name, Pin to Taskbar, Close.

Comment: I use a desktop icon for Ubuntu and each time I double click it I get a new terminal.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. #### Windows Terminal Way:

   Windows Terminal is a terminal emulator for Windows 10 written by Microsoft.

   - Download it from [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701)
   - Click on Drop-down and choose Ubuntu. If it doesn't exists add that. See: [How do I add application on Windows Terminal?](https://superuser.com/q/1456187/1049284)
2. #### CMD Way:

   This could be achieved. You need to open multiple windows of command prompt and type `ubuntu` or `ubuntu1604` or `ubuntu1804` depending on the version you've downloaded on all the prompts. You'll get multiple terminals.

   In this screenshot I have opened one "Terminal" in app and four in `cmd`

   [image]

Comment: Hey that achieves exactly what I was after. Why didn't I think of that!

Comment: Its not even needed to use cmd to open the other ubuntu terminals. You can just open them by typing ubuntu when opening your start menu.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you have multiple WSL windows open like in your picture. I can open a CMD or Ubuntu terminal, but each one opens in its own tab, and I do not see any way to split the screen and put terminals side by side...

Comment: @AlfaBravo Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Can you please provide a screenshot (video would be best)? This can be a problem from Windows side. I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe I said it wrong, I just wanted to know if it was possible with Windows Terminal to have a multi-window setup like your picture (At least the 4 windows in the back). Like can I have 2 ubuntu terminals side by side? I have looked every where on the terminal window to split the screen but find nothing... :/

Comment: Ahh, I got it now - and the answer is YES!! Have been looking for this for so long.  :)

Comment: @AlfaBravo Were you trying using Windows Terminal? The screenshot I attached is of command prompt not of Windows Terminal.

Comment: I see now, I just thought it was CMD inside windows terminal. But I got WT also split up in multi-windows now, running WSL in all of them...

Comment: @AlfaBravo Great!!! :)

Answer (score 45):

You can <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click the Ubuntu icon to open another instance of the Ubuntu app/terminal.

Or if you have it pinned to your taskbar and it's one of the first 10 icons (e.g. 2nd icon), you could also do <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> as a keyboard shortcut to open a new instance, after doing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to open it initially.

Comment: Can you please explain more precisely what you mean?  For example, do you mean “Hold the ‘Shift’ key while selecting ‘Ubuntu’ from the menu.”?  (“Shift+Ubuntu” would normally mean “Hold the ‘Shift’ key while pressing the ‘Ubuntu’ key.”  Does your keyboard have an ‘Ubuntu’ key?) … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: `Shift`-`click` means to hold the `Shift` key while clicking on the Ubuntu icon. This worked for me.

Comment: thanks so much. too easy :)

Answer (score 4):

Try using a different terminal cmd is awful, ConEmu https://conemu.github.io/ on windows works great. After you install it you can open multiple tabs or split vertical/horizontal like terminator on Linux using hotkey Ctrl+Shift+O or Ctrl+Shift+E.

Also to speed up WSL on windows (IO is so slow) There are a few tutorials out there such as https://medium.com/@leandrw/speeding-up-wsl-i-o-up-than-5x-fast-saving-a-lot-of-battery-life-cpu-usage-c3537dd03c74 (sacrifice some security tho)

Comment: Great tip. I did come across something like this but hope there would be an easier solution. Opening 'Ubuntu' in the CommandPrompt seems to achieve what I was after. Kind regards

Comment: I like a lot Cmder as a cmd replacement, it's based on ConEmu with a nice config

Answer (score 1):

I think you will love [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html). They have a free version that has all the features. Paid version gets support.

It has been my workspace for WSL for many years and I love it. It has a snappy, native XWindows system that allows you to use GUI applications if you want (I use RStudio this way, as well as Synaptic on occasion).

Answer (score 0):

Right click the ubuntu icon in the windows taskbar and then left click the Ubuntu 1X.0X LTS, there will be a new window popping out.